# How to have different color for dropdown label and dropdown list text in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to use dropdown, and want to have `Colors.white` for the selected text, and `Colors.black54` for the text of drop down list. But when I tried to use `color` attribute and change it to White, it also change the color of drop down text.

```
DropdownButton<String>(
                    //this changed the color of both text, intial text as well dropdown text color
                    dropdownColor: Colors.white,
                    value: value,
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    icon: CircleAvatar(
                      radius: 12,
                      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                      child: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
                    ),
                    items: places.map((String value) {
                      return new DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                        value: value,
                        child: new Text(
                          value,
                         //I tried giving text style here , but same result 
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                        ),
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                    onChanged: (_) {
                      setState(() {
                        value = _;
                      });
                    },
                  )
```

Here is the picture of it.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Okay I found the Solution using `selectedItemBuilder` attribute of `dropdown`

```
 final List<String> places = ['Delhi', 'Mumbai', 'Kerela', 'Agra'];

 DropdownButton<String>(
                    selectedItemBuilder: (_) {
                      return places
                          .map((e) => Container(
                                alignment: Alignment.center,
                                child: Text(
                                  e,
                                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                ),
                              ))
                          .toList();
                    },
                    value: value,
                    icon: CircleAvatar(
                      radius: 12,
                      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                      child: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
                    ),
                    items: places.map((String value) {
                      return new DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                        value: value,
                        child: new Text(
                          value,
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black54),
                        ),
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                    onChanged: (_) {
                      setState(() {
                        value = _;
                      });
                    },
                  )
```

Here is the result

[image]
[image]